# What is the correct way to read and get specific string then place it in a csv file?

Tags: python

I have this [sample_vsdt.txt](https://pastebin.com/vCjjGQxe) file containing SHA-1 and description like this inside of my txt file:

```
Scanning samples_extracted\02b809d4edee752d9286677ea30e8a76114aa324->(Microsoft RTF 6008-0)
->Found Virus [Possible_SCRDL]

Scanning samples_extracted\0349e0101d8458b6d05860fbee2b4a6d7fa2038d->(Adobe Portable Document Format(PDF) 6015-0)
->Found Virus [TROJ_FRS.VSN11I18]
```

**Example:**

```
SHA-1: 02b809d4edee752d9286677ea30e8a76114aa324
Description:(Microsoft RTF 6008-0)
```

**Problem:**

My task is to list those SHA-1 and Description in my txt file then list it in a csv file, I was able to do that using regex,prefix and delimeter. However this example is what makes it hard for me:

```
Scanning samples_extracted\0191a23ee122bdb0c69008971e365ec530bf03f5
     - Invoice_No_94497.doc->Found Virus [Trojan.4FEC5F36]->(MIME 6010-0)

     - Found 1/3 Viruses in samples_extracted\0191a23ee122bdb0c69008971e365ec530bf03f5
```

It has different line pattern and I only want to get the SHA-1 in the first line not the 4th line and get the description in the second line.

**Output:**

The output went wrong because the description (MIME 6010-0) was put in the SHA-1 column.

```
0191a23ee122bdb0c69008971e365ec530bf03f5    
(MIME 6010-0)   
02b809d4edee752d9286677ea30e8a76114aa324    (Microsoft RTF 6008-0)
0349e0101d8458b6d05860fbee2b4a6d7fa2038d    (Adobe Portable Document Format(PDF) 6015-0)
035a7afca8b72cf1c05f6062814836ee31091559    (Adobe Portable Document Format(PDF) 6015-0)
```

**Code**

```
import csv
import re

INPUTFILE = 'samples_vsdt.txt'
OUTPUTFILE = 'output.csv'
PREFIX = '\\'
DELIMITER = '->'
DELIMITER2 = ']->'
PREFIX2 = ' - '
def read_text_file(inputfile):
    data = []
    with open(inputfile, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        if re.search(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]{40}', line) and not "Found" in line: # <----
            line = line.split(PREFIX, 1)[-1]
            parts = line.split(DELIMITER)
            data.append(parts)

        else:

            if "->(" in line and "Found" in line :
                matched_words=(re.search(r'\(.*?\)',line))
                sha =(re.search(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]{40}',line))

                if matched_words!=None:
                    matched_words=matched_words.group()
                    matched_words=matched_words.split("]->")

                    data.append(matched_words)
    #data.append(parts)                  
    return data

def write_csv_file(data, outputfile):
    with open(outputfile, 'wb') as csvfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        for row in data:
            csvwriter.writerow(row)

def main():
    data = read_text_file(INPUTFILE)
    write_csv_file(data, OUTPUTFILE)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is the full content of my text file:
[sample_vsdt.txt](https://pastebin.com/vCjjGQxe)

Answer (score 0):

If there is no description found, find it in the next line.

```
import re

patsha = re.compile(r'Scanning samples_extracted\\([a-z0-9]{40})')
patdesc = re.compile(r'->(\(.*\))')

with open("samples_vsdt.txt") as f:
    sha = None
    for l in f:
        if sha is None:
            sha = patsha.match(l)
        if sha:
            desc = patdesc.search(l)
            if desc:
                print(sha.group(1)+','+desc.group(1))
                sha = None
```